# How can we remove Order History from a customers account page?

Tags: order-history

So I'm attempting to remove these sections of the Account page, i'm unable to find the reference block can someone help? [image]

Comment: you only want to remove on Account Dashboard or on every link in sidebar

Comment: Just the sidebar "My Orders" and "Recently Ordered" - Along with Recent Orders under the Address Book.

Answer (score 2):

Please use below code in your **default.xml** file of your theme

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="sale.reorder.sidebar" remove="true" />
        <referenceBlock name="customer_account_dashboard_top" remove="true" />

    </body>
</page>
```

clean cache and check again !!

Comment: Can you confirm where this file is? I've tried editing it in the /customtheme/theme/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml and it doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: Please put file on this path /customtheme/theme/Magento_Sales/layout/default.xml

Comment: I did this and it still didn't get rid of the elements I wanted, any other recommendations on where to put the file?